# How do I make the Console window show when a program is running in non-debug mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xna

I'm writting this XNA game and in order to help me debug some problems, I'd like to see the output I'm writing to the Console in my code .. Problem is the Console window in Visual Studio 2008 will only show when I run the program in Debug mode .. And in this mode I can see the stuff I'm writing to the console in my code ... However I can't find any way to also force the console to be visible when I'm running the code in non-Debug mode ..

Any suggestions ?

Comment: if you're debugging it, why aren't you in debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add a `Console.ReadLine();` to the section(s) of code that you would like to debug?